# pythonanywhere - issues with JavaScript files loading in admin console

Tags: javascript, python, django, pythonanywhere

having issues with js files loading in the admin console, hindering the activities of the admin console. Errors attached.

[image]

[image]

Tried entering the static file path under the static section on the pythonanywhere.

[image]

`home/<username>/<name of the app>/static/js`

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "static" in the PythonAnywhere help pages, you will find a number of help pages about setting up static files and debugging issues with them.